# This is a guessing game I need to make for school. I am giving hints for the player but for some reason the hints seem to be wrong

Tags: python

```
    import time
import random


numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
right = random.choice(numbers)

print(right) #<=========== testing purposes
```

Random number generator above, no problems

```
print("Hey there, I want to play a game, ")
time.sleep(2)
print("You have to guess the number in my head, ")
time.sleep(2)
Guess = input("Guess the number I am thinking in my head: ")

if Guess > str(right) :
  print("Greater than the number")
elif Guess < str(right) :
  print("Less than the number")
elif Guess == str(right) :
  print("You got the right number,  on your first try somehow...")
  time.sleep(3)
  quit()

time.sleep(2)

print("I will give another chance!")
time.sleep(1)
print("Here's a hint")
time.sleep(1.5)

bruh = 5


if right == int(bruh):
  print("a mix of both in the early alphabet and the early-half of the alphabet")
elif right > int(bruh) :
  print("it's somewhere close to the early-half of the alphabet")
if right < int(bruh) :
  print("It's pretty early in the alphabet")



guessv2 = input("So what is your guess?: ")
```

It's at this part where it becomes misleading for some reason and whenever I intentionally put a lower number than the answer in the input, it says what it's not supposed to say. For example, if the number chosen by the computer was 5 and I put 4 in the input, it would say that the number was  lesser.

```
if guessv2 == str(right) :
  print("You got the number right! Good job!")
  time.sleep(3)
  quit()
elif guessv2 < str(right) :
  print("Greater than the number")
elif guessv2 > str(right) :
  print("Less than the number!")

time.sleep(3)

print("This is your last chance, if you get this wrong you don't win!")
time.sleep(1)

print("Here's a better hint: ")
time.sleep(0.5)

if right == int(bruh):
  print(":-)")
elif right > int(bruh) :
  print("greater than 5")
if right < int(bruh) :
  print("less than 5")
```

Comment: You're comparing string representations of the numbers, not the value of the numbers. You want `int(guess)` not `str(right)`

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you simply have a comparison backward:

```py
if guessv2 == str(right) :
  print("You got the number right! Good job!")
  time.sleep(3)
  quit()
elif guessv2 < str(right) : # <------ should be guessv2 > str(right)
  print("Greater than the number")
elif guessv2 > str(right) : # <------ should be guessv2 < str(right)
  print("Less than the number!")
```